# Using SDL_MapRGBA is being really slow. Is this normal?

Tags: c++, sdl

I am currently trying to make some very Basic drawing software which means I with be working with SDL_MapRGBA for pixel manipulation however I have noticed that this is being very processor intensive.
For Example this code:

```
void fill_bkg()//sets the background to bkg_c with an alhpa of 255
{
     for(forl = 0;forl < window_w * window_h;forl++)
     {
         *(winpix + forl) = SDL_MapRGBA(smpl->format,bkg_c.r,bkg_c.g,bkg_c.b,255);
     }
}
```

is using 11% of my processor (at 60 fps) and it only fills the background.
bkg_c is a SDL_Color.
winpix points to the surface pixel data.
window_w/h are set to 1280 and 720. So is there a quicker way to do this such as a method using SDL_BlitSurface or is SDL_MapRGBA just slow?
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About a million separate operations is almost always slow. To fill surface with one color, you should use `SDL_FillRect`. To fill it with pre-defined image (i.e. not constant color) - use `SDL_BlitSurface`.